# Delete element from python list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python. I am trying to delete an element from this **python list**

```
qundl_arry = [[u'WIKI/DIS.11'], [u'WIKI/HD.11'], [u'WIKI/MCD1.11'], 
 [u'WIKI/AZO.11'], [u'WIKI/BBY1.11'], [u'WIKI/HRB.11']]
```

The element I want to delete is:

```
alpha = [u'WIKI/MCD1.11']
```

When I execute the below code

```
np.delete(qundl_arry,alpha)
```

I get the below error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'WIKI/MCD1.11'
```

Comment: Read the docs again.

Comment: not sure which docs you are referring too. Is something specific you have in mind ?

Comment: The docs for `np.delete`.

Comment: Also, that is a `list`, not a `numpy` array.

Comment: Thanks that helps... I believe, the removal of element is dependent on the location of element rather then actual value. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a regular Python `list`, not a `numpy` array.

Just use something like:

```
>>> qundl_arry = [
    [u'WIKI/DIS.11'], [u'WIKI/HD.11'], [u'WIKI/MCD1.11'], 
    [u'WIKI/AZO.11'], [u'WIKI/BBY1.11'], [u'WIKI/HRB.11']
]
>>> alpha = [u'WIKI/MCD1.11']
>>> index = qundl_arry.index(alpha)
>>> index
2
>>> qundl_arry.pop(index)
[u'WIKI/MCD1.11']
>>> qundl_arry
[[u'WIKI/DIS.11'], [u'WIKI/HD.11'], [u'WIKI/AZO.11'], [u'WIKI/BBY1.11'], [u'WIKI/HRB.11']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) you will see that `numpy.delete` returns:

> A copy of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. Note that **delete does not occur in-place**.

So, to make it work you will need:

```
qundl_arry = np.delete(qundl_arry,alpha)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is directed towards someone using **`numpy arrays`**.
The author of this question was actually refering to **`python lists`**.
Even though this answer is not relevant to the question anymore, I will leave it here since it could be useful to someone else.

---

Assuming that you do not know the index, you can create a new array with all the elements of 
`qundl_arry` except when `qundl_arry == alpha`.

Example:

```
qundl_arry = np.array([[u'WIKI/DIS.11'], [u'WIKI/HD.11'], [u'WIKI/MCD1.11'], [u'WIKI/AZO.11'], [u'WIKI/BBY1.11'], [u'WIKI/HRB.11']])

alpha = u'WIKI/MCD1.11'

qundl_arry_new = qundl_arry[qundl_arry != alpha]

print(qundl_arry_new)
# ['WIKI/DIS.11' 'WIKI/HD.11' 'WIKI/AZO.11' 'WIKI/BBY1.11' 'WIKI/HRB.11']
```

---

Note:

`np.delete` returns an array. Similar to the code above, `np.delete` will leave `qundl_arry` unchanged.